# How to return integer as a promise in from external function in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I wrote an external function that accepts a parameter and counts some occurrences which are stored as an integer in a variable totalNumToAck. I then try to return that calculated integer as a fulfilled promise and later use it. I call the function and successfully pass the parameter to it. It does what it needs to do but I have trouble returning the result.
In the code where I try to use it, it is always 0. Can you please point me to what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: actually looks like the second method works and my actual problem is in the external function itself due to async execution. The code gets to the line: deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck); 
before for loop is complete and thus always return 0. So the new question is how to make my return wait for "for loop" to finish?

My very simplified code is below:

```
//The function I want to call, which is in a different file:


MyExternalFunction(numOfLines)  {

    var totalNumToAck =0;
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();


    for (var i = 0; i < numOfLines; ++i) {  
            //code to analyze the page      
            if (somecondition) {
                totalNumToAck++;
                }

    }
    console.log('found' + totalNumToAck + 'elements');
    deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck);
    return deferred.promise;

};
```

---

```
//The code where I try to use the function - Edit: this actually works! but the problem is in ext function

myextstuff.MyExternalFunction(5).then(function (totalNumToAck ) {
    console.log ("number returned from ext function: " + totalNumToAck );
    //other code that needs to use integer value that external function returns
});
```

---

```
//Also tried - Edit: this actually works too! but the problem is in ext function
response = myextstuff.MyExternalFunction(5);
response.then(function(cellValue){   
    console.log ("number returned from ext function: " + cellValue);
    totalNumToAck =  cellValue;
    //other code that needs to use integer value that external function returns
        });
```

Comment: Are there any asynchronous actions within the for loop in your external function?

Comment: yes, there are. it looks like  deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck); does not wait for the loop to complete. How can I fix that?

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) may be of use to you in this situation. Could you tell me what the nature of the loop is?  Are there many async actions within it? Are there any other actions within the if statement within the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with for loop. My External function now looks like:

```
MyExternalFunction(numOfLines)  {
    var totalNumToAck =0;
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    browser.wait(function () {
       return SomeElementThatIKnowIsPresent.isPresent();
    }, 50000).then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfLines; ++i) {  
            //code to analyze the page      
            if (somecondition) {
                totalNumToAck++;
                }

    }
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('found' + totalNumToAck + 'elements');
        deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

This ensures that for loop will finish and only then deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck); will happen. Thank you for anyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following attempt

```
MyExternalFunction(numOfLines)  {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var totalNumToAck = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < numOfLines; ++i) {
            //code to analyze the page      
            if (somecondition) {
                totalNumToAck++;
            }
        }
        console.log('found' + totalNumToAck + 'elements');
        resolve(totalNumToAck);
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think my problem is not with how I return the value, but with the fact that deferred.fulfill(totalNumToAck); does not wait for the loop to complete so it always returns 0. Do you know how can I fix that?